# MySQL: joining two tables

Tags: php, mysql, join, mac-address

I have two tables in the database, 
one is  **transactions** table:

```
id    mac            timestamp     siteid


1     C8BCC8BD7684   1365987620      5


2     8C2DAA4CB9E6   1365995414      4
```

another one is **equipment_details** table:

```
id       mac_address       organization 


1        00:00:0E          Fujitsu limited


2        00:00:00          Xerox corporation


3        C8:BC:C8          Apple, inc.


4        8C:2D:AA:         Apple, inc.
```

I need to join these two tables. So the output table should be like,

```
 id   mac            timestamp     siteid      organization

1     C8BCC8BD7684   1365987620      5         Apple, inc.


2     8C2DAA4CB9E6   1365995414      4         Apple, inc.
```

Can I use something like wordwrap(substr(`transactions.mac`, 0, 6),2,":",true) to retreive the first 6 letters from the transactions.mac? I have tried the below code, but I am getting mysql error:

```
"SELECT transactions.mac,equipment_details.mac_address,equipment_details.organization FROM `transactions`, `equipment_details` WHERE transactions.mac LIKE equipment_details.mac_address+'%' "
```

Any help much be appreciated!

Comment: What is the error output? Did you select your db?

Comment: If you want to join 2 tables then  there must be a relavaent KEY between the two tables

Comment: yes, I did. error is :"Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '+'%'' at line 1

Comment: @Gautam3164 : yeah, Can I use mac address as key? I want to select whether equipment_details.mac_address and transactions.mac(first 6 charcters with colon) are equal.

Comment: yes ofcourse you can add then via mac address then try my ans coming..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*,
        b.Organization
FROM    transactions a
        INNER JOIN equipment_details b
            ON SUBSTRING(a.mac, 1,6) = REPLACE(b.mac_address, ':', '')
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e1847/3)

OUTPUT

```
╔════╦══════════════╦════════════╦════════╦══════════════╗
║ ID ║     MAC      ║ TIMESTAMP  ║ SITEID ║ ORGANIZATION ║
╠════╬══════════════╬════════════╬════════╬══════════════╣
║  1 ║ C8BCC8BD7684 ║ 1365987620 ║      5 ║ Apple, inc.  ║
║  2 ║ 8C2DAA4CB9E6 ║ 1365995414 ║      4 ║ Apple, inc.  ║
╚════╩══════════════╩════════════╩════════╩══════════════╝
```

The only problem with this one is that it doesn't uses index and will perform very slow if you have large database. The best way you can do is to normalize properly the tables `:)`

Comment: It's very slow because it will not use an index even if you have define one since the columns used to join were processed in a function. Here's a suggested design, why not put a column in the table transaction named `mac_six` which contains the first 6 characters of the `MAC` and define an index on it. On the second table, remove the `:` from the `Mac_address`, define an index and it will perform faster.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
SELECT transactions.mac,equipment_details.mac_address,equipment_details.organization
FROM `transactions`
JOIN 'equipment_details'
ON equipment_details.mac_address = REPLACE(SUBSTRING('transactions.mac',6),":","")
```

you dont need like statement for this now...if you want to compare with LIKE then its syntax should be

```
WHERE transactions.mac LIKE equipment_details.mac_address = 'my_string%'
```

Comment: still there is an error: Message:SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '+'%'' at line 4. (I am using zend framework).

Comment: Thanks for the update and now the mysql query is error free. But I am getting an empty array. I was wondering that the updated code will search like "ON 00:00:0E =00000E". So it should be empty. Is there any way to add : for SUBSTRING('transactions.mac',6) ")?

Comment: I am getting an empty array. I am checking it.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SELECT tr.mac,ed.mac_address,ed.organization
FROM `transactions` tr
JOIN 'equipment_details' ed
ON ed.mac_address = REPLACE(SUBSTRING('tr.mac',6),":","")
```

With Replace you can directly compare the mac address with the ":" and the ones with no ":"

hope it's helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this too. Inner Join may help you to join two tables. I guess your Primary key is 'id' in both tables & you've referenced 'id' as a foreign key in equipment_details table.

```
select tr.id,tr.mac,tr.timestamp,tr.siteid,ed.organisation from transactions tr inner join equipment_details ed ON ed.mac_address = SUBSTRING('transactions.mac',6) where tr.id = ed.id
```